# Xcode6 xliff localisations. NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue and Localizable.strings in base language

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have a project with English as a base/reference/development language. I need to localize it. I use Xcode6.1

I need to use `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` macro since it provides ability to set id, default text and comment. I don't intend to use tables and bundles. I need keys and values to be different because I want to avoid this

```
"Do you want to cancel download?" = "Do you want to cancel download?"
```

and instead have

```
"downloadscreen.dialog.cancel.label" = "Do you want to cancel download?"
```

When I export .xliff file for localization I get, well, `en.xliff` file which can then be localized and returned to me as `fr.xliff` and when I import it I will get `Localizable.strings` for French created/updated. Although no `Localizable.strings` for English.

The app still works fine since I have given default values in `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` but lets say translators or reviewers can change some wording for given id to "Do you *really* want to cancel download?". If this happens it means for me that I have to manually replace default values in code to get updated translations. Previously I used `NSLocalizedString` with id, in the form I needed, and then I had to add proper values in `Localizable.strings` for English but it had all sorts of troubles with regeneration of strings file and other stuff like that.

Can someone suggest me how to deal with this situation or share his experience using `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` in Xcode6?